# How this component would look like without destructuring?

Tags: reactjs, formik

I have component `Form` in which I use a `Formik` library:

```
const Form = () => {
    const {handleSubmit, values, handleChange} = useFormik({
      initialValues: {
          username: '',
          email: '',
          password: '',
          confirm_password: '',
      },
      onSubmit: (formValues) => {
          console.log('submit', formValues);
      },    
    });

   return (
   <form className="fform" onSubmit={handleSubmit} onChange={handleChange}/>
       <input name="username" value={values.username} onChange={handleChange} />
       <input name="email" value={values.email} onChange={handleChange} />
       <input name="password" value={values.password} onChange={handleChange} />
       <input name="confirm_password" value={values.confirm_password} onChange={handleChange} />
       <button type="submit">Submit Form</button>
   </form>
   );
};
```

Once a teacher was saying:

> here I do destructuring:

`const {handleSubmit, values, handleChange} =`

But how would look like `Form` component  if did not use `destructuring` in this case?
That is, how can a component be written without destructuring but to have `useFormik` methods present in the `Form` component? Because I need these methods in form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could get the value of `useFormik` in a single constant

```
const useFormikObj = useFormik({
  initialValues: {
    username: '',
    email: '',
    password: '',
    confirm_password: '',
  },
  onSubmit: (formValues) => {
    console.log('submit', formValues);
  },    
});
```

`useFormik` will then return an object that contains `handleSubmit, values, handleChange` (according to your example)

so now you'll to create a separate constant for each of the properties you're trying to access

```
const handleSubmit = useFormikObj.handleSubmit
const values = useFormikObj.values
const handleChange = useFormikObj.values
```

and now the rest of your app should look the same

**Another Example**

If you have an object like this

```
const obj = {
  name: 'Andrew',
  age: 27,
}
```

you can either access those properties through the regular notation

```
obj.name //Andrew
obj.age //27
```

But if you have to use that multiple times you might want to avoid using `obj.` every time, so you could use destructuring like this

```
const { name, age } = obj
```

if it was an array it would be like this

```
const array = [1, 2, 3]
const [ x1, x2, x3 ] = array //x1 = 1, x2 = 2 and so on
```

You can check more on descructuring [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the returned value to and object variable

```
const res = useFormik({
```

And you can use this object

```
<form className="fform" onSubmit={res.handleSubmit} onChange={res.handleChange}/>
       <input name="username" value={res.values.username} onChange={res.handleChange} />
...
```